# Why does this method return 2 values if I only ask for one and there is no sort of conditional statement anywhere?

Tags: java

I'm writing this very simple program from this one PDF called Think AP Java, and I can't seem to wrap my head around this:

When I write

```
public static double method_1(double x)
{
    double result =( x*(Math.exp(-x)  )    ) + (Math.sqrt(1-Math.exp(-x) )    );

    System.out.println(result);

    return result;  
}
```

I get the output of:    1.1629395387920924

But when I write:

```
public static double multAdd(double a, double b, double c)
{

    double result = (a*b) +c;

    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

and

```
public static double method_2(double x)
{

    double result_1 =  (multAdd(1.0,  (Math.exp(-x)), 0.0)) ;
    double result_2 = (Math.sqrt(1.0-Math.exp(-x)));

    double final_result =  result_1 + result_2;
    System.out.println(final_result);

    return final_result;
}
```

The output for method_2 is:    0.36787944117144233 AND 1.1629395387920924, printed directly over one another.

What can explain the cause of this?
Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I'm only just a beginner.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `method_2`, you are also implicitly calling `multAdd`. As per the definition of `multAdd`, you are printing the result of `(a*b) + c)`. Once that `method_2` is done with the call to `multAdd`, the execution will proceed with the remainder of the code in your method.

Eventually, it will reach the print statement (similar to what you have in the `multAdd` method). Once it hits this line, the program will print the second line. This is why you have two print statements when you call `method_2`.

If you want to show just one result, what you would need to do would be to omit the print statements from your methods and work with the returned value. As you can notice, all of your methods are retuning the value that they are printing.

So, you could do something like so: `System.out.println(method_1(arg1));` and `System.out.println(method_2(arg1));`

The above code should print only two values, which are the ones you are really after.

Comment: Yes! This worked exactly as I had wanted to. I cannot believe that I didn't figure that out myself. At any rate, sincerely, thank you!